# Python Zeep missing provided XML Attribute

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

I'm trying to use Python Zeep library to create a XML which is being send to the Barra API. However the "Path" attribute of the "PortfolioNode" is not being filled by Zeep. When I create similar code with the Python suds library it is working as intended.

WSDL in .txt: https://gofile.io/?c=CvRHVD

```
import zeep
from lxml import etree
from barra_module.barra_config import user_id, password, client_id

url = "https://www.barraone.com/axis2/services/BDTService?wsdl"

client = zeep.client.Client(url)
factory = client.type_factory('ns0')

# Doesn't work because Path is not being filled for some reason.
node = factory.PortfolioNode(
    Path="SOMEPATH",
    PortfolioName="Google",
    Owner="workflow",
    )

# I don't know why, but this weird syntax is necessary
nodes = factory.PortfolioNodes(
    _value_1=[{'PortfolioNode': [node]}]
)

tree = factory.PortfolioTree(
    PortfolioNodes=nodes,
    TreeName="MyTree",
    Owner=user_id,
)

# Create xml file for the SubmitImportJob call
soup_object = client.create_message(client.service, 'SubmitImportJob', user_id, client_id, password, "my_job_name", None, None, None, [tree], None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
tree = etree.ElementTree(soup_object)
tree.write("debug_zeep.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

The resulting XML is:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:SubmitImportJobRequest xmlns:ns0="http://barra.com/cp/bdtbeans">
      <ns0:User>***</ns0:User>
      <ns0:Client>***</ns0:Client>
      <ns0:Password>***</ns0:Password>
      <ns0:JobName>my_job_name</ns0:JobName>
      <ns0:PortfolioTree TreeName="MyTree" Owner="***" BottomUpAggregation="false">
        <ns0:PortfolioNodes>
          <ns0:PortfolioNode Owner="workflow" Path="NotSet" AggregationType="NONE" PortfolioName="Google"/>
        </ns0:PortfolioNodes>
      </ns0:PortfolioTree>
    </ns0:SubmitImportJobRequest>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Where the error is in: `Path="NotSet"`. Which should be `Path="SOMEPATH"`. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you run client.wsdl.dump() just below client and share the result?

Comment: @theone1one https://gofile.io/?c=CvRHVD let me know if you don't trust gofile.io or if there are easier ways to share this.